# Conditionally dispatching side-effects

Tags: redux, redux-observable

Say I have a search component that searches based on tags selected by the user (Think [Pocket](http://getpocket.com)). If the user deselects all tags, I know the result of the search is going to be null; there is no need to hit the server. How can I refactor this epic to conditionally run the side-effect?

```
const removeTagEpic = (action$: any, store: any) => 
  action$
    .ofType(types.REMOVE_SELECTED_TAG)
    .map((action: any) => action.payload)
    .mergeMap((tag: any) => {
      //only do this is store.getState().tags > 0
      ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users/dwaynelavon`)
        .flatMap(response => 
          Observable.concat(
            Observable.of(actions.fetchingProfiles(true)),
            Observable.of(actions.fetchProfilesFulfilled(profiles)),
            Observable.of(actions.fetchingProfiles(false))
          )
        )
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use `filter` operator and check the tag in there?

```
const removeTagEpic = (action$: any, store: any) => 
  action$
    .ofType(types.REMOVE_SELECTED_TAG)
    .filter(_ => store.getState().tags > 0)
    .map((action: any) => action.payload)
    .mergeMap((tag: any) => {
      ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users/dwaynelavon`)
        .flatMap(response => 
          Observable.concat(
            Observable.of(actions.fetchingProfiles(true)),
            Observable.of(actions.fetchProfilesFulfilled(profiles)),
            Observable.of(actions.fetchingProfiles(false))
          )
        )
    })
```

The source of `types.REMOVE_SELECTED_TAG` won't be emitted if the condition is not met.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out like right before you responded haha